# How can I add a fee to a completed and paid Woocommerce order?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, authorize.net

I have a Woocommerce website.  I need to add a fee to an existing paid order. How can I add a fee and have the credit card charged even though the customer has already submitted the payment information (which we don't store)?  Is it possibile? Do I need a plugin?

Comment: Which payment gateway did they use to make the purchase?

Comment: Authorize.net - I would like to be able to add a fee and have woocommerce charge the card without the customer having to re-enter their credit card information.

Answer (score 1):

You can't charge an additional fee if you already captured the full amount the customer authorised.

The reason is because online payments when done through a payment gateway are nearly always a two-step process involving:

**Authorisation:** As the name indicates, this is where the customer authorises that a certain amount will be charged against their card by the merchant. Your payment processor will verify that the customer actually has the funds and block them so that the customer can't spend them (to the customer it'll look like it was already deducted).

**Capture:** This is where the funds actually "move" from the customer's account to the merchant's account (technically nothing moves, just credit and debit accounting entries are made at the banks involved).

http://www.paymentsgateway.com.au/what-you-need-to-know/payments-gateway-authorization-and-capture has a good explanation on this process.

Authorize.net uses the same model as you can see from their documentation: https://support.authorize.net/authkb/index?page=content&id=A510

**What to do in your situation?**

If this is an isolated incident where you were meant to charge the customer a fee but forgot to, then either have them pay through a different way or waive the fee.

If you need to charge a fee for every single customer then they *must* **authorise** the total amount, even if you **capture** for example 95% on order completion and 5% afterwards.

Whether you can do these partial captures depends on Authorize.net and how you set up WooCommerce.

Answer (score 0):

I do this all the time on authorized.net .you use transaction search to find the transaction then you click view rebillable transactions and if the transaction was recent it will be among the rebillable transactions. Then you put a checkmark on that transaction and you put in the amount to bill in addition to the original transaction and then you click submit and you check to make sure you get the result "success."